# I can't find file `xkeyval´

Tags: miktex, texstudio, xkeyval

I am writing a document using TexStudio and MikTeX as package source. Today I updated some packages including *xkeyval*. Now every compilation throws an error (I can't find file `xkeyval´.) I tried to reinstall the package with MikTex and also manually but nothing changes.
Is there any way to fix this or find out which of the packages relies on xkeyval?

[image]

The log file:

`````
This is pdfTeX, Version 3.14159265-2.6-1.40.21 (MiKTeX 20.11) (preloaded format=pdflatex 2020.11.25)  25 NOV 2020 09:07
entering extended mode
**./main.tex
(main.tex
LaTeX2e <2020-10-01> patch level 2
L3 programming layer <2020-10-27> xparse <2020-03-03> (Struktur/preamble.tex
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/latex/koma-script\scrreprt.cls"
Document Class: scrreprt 2020/09/21 v3.32 KOMA-Script document class (report)
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/latex/koma-script\scrkbase.sty"
Package: scrkbase 2020/09/21 v3.32 KOMA-Script package (KOMA-Script-dependent b
asics and keyval usage)

("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/latex/koma-script\scrbase.sty"
Package: scrbase 2020/09/21 v3.32 KOMA-Script package (KOMA-Script-independent 
basics and keyval usage)

("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/latex/koma-script\scrlfile.sty"
Package: scrlfile 2020/09/21 v3.32 KOMA-Script package (file load hooks)

("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/latex/koma-script\scrlfile-hook.sty"
Package: scrlfile-hook 2020/09/21 v3.32 KOMA-Script package (using LaTeX hooks)


LaTeX3 Info: Defining command \BeforeFile with sig. 'm' on line 61.


LaTeX3 Info: Defining command \AfterFile with sig. 'm' on line 65.


LaTeX3 Info: Defining command \BeforeClass with sig. 'm' on line 69.


LaTeX3 Info: Defining command \BeforePackage with sig. 'm' on line 73.


LaTeX3 Info: Defining command \AfterAtEndOfClass with sig. 'smo+m' on line 83.


LaTeX3 Info: Defining command \AfterAtEndOfPackage with sig. 'smo+m' on line
(LaTeX3)     93.


LaTeX3 Info: Defining command \scrlfile@AfterClass with sig. 'smo+m' on line
(LaTeX3)     173.


LaTeX3 Info: Defining command \AfterClass with sig. '' on line 174.


LaTeX3 Info: Defining command \scrlfile@AfterPackage with sig. 'smo+m' on line
(LaTeX3)     191.


LaTeX3 Info: Defining command \AfterPackage with sig. '' on line 192.


LaTeX3 Info: Defining command \ReplaceInput with sig. '' on line 193.


LaTeX3 Info: Defining command \ReplaceClass with sig. 'mm' on line 196.


LaTeX3 Info: Defining command \ReplacePackage with sig. 'mm' on line 199.


LaTeX3 Info: Defining command \UnReplaceInput with sig. '' on line 200.


LaTeX3 Info: Defining command \UnReplaceClass with sig. 'm' on line 203.


LaTeX3 Info: Defining command \UnReplacePackage with sig. 'mm' on line 206.


LaTeX3 Info: Defining command \PreventPackageFromLoading with sig. 's+om' on
(LaTeX3)     line 234.


LaTeX3 Info: Defining command \StorePreventPackageFromLoading with sig. 'm' on
(LaTeX3)     line 242.


LaTeX3 Info: Defining command \ResetPreventPackageFromLoading with sig. '' on
(LaTeX3)     line 247.


LaTeX3 Info: Defining command \UnPreventPackageFromLoading with sig. 'sm' on
(LaTeX3)     line 261.


LaTeX3 Info: Defining command \BeforeClosingMainAux with sig. 'om' on line
(LaTeX3)     274.


LaTeX3 Info: Defining command \AfterReadingMainAux with sig. 'om' on line 287.


LaTeX3 Info: Defining command \protected@immediate@write with sig. 'm+m+m' on
(LaTeX3)     line 298.


("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/latex/koma-script\scrlogo.sty"
Package: scrlogo 2020/09/21 v3.32 KOMA-Script package (logo)
)))
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/latex/graphics\keyval.sty"
Package: keyval 2014/10/28 v1.15 key=value parser (DPC)
\KV@toks@=\toks15
)))
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/latex/koma-script\tocbasic.sty"
Package: tocbasic 2020/09/21 v3.32 KOMA-Script package (handling toc-files)
\scr@dte@tocline@numberwidth=\skip47
\scr@dte@tocline@numbox=\box47
)
Package tocbasic Info: babel extension for `toc' omitted
(tocbasic)             because of missing \bbl@set@language on input line 137.
Class scrreprt Info: File `scrsize12pt.clo' used to setup font sizes on input l
ine 2434.

("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/latex/koma-script\scrsize12pt.clo"
File: scrsize12pt.clo 2020/09/21 v3.32 KOMA-Script font size class option (12pt
)
)
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/latex/koma-script\typearea.sty"
Package: typearea 2020/09/21 v3.32 KOMA-Script package (type area)
\ta@bcor=\skip48
\ta@div=\count175
\ta@hblk=\skip49
\ta@vblk=\skip50
\ta@temp=\skip51
\footheight=\skip52
Package typearea Info: These are the values describing the layout:
(typearea)             DIV  = 12
(typearea)             BCOR = 28.45274pt
(typearea)             \paperwidth      = 597.50793pt
(typearea)              \textwidth      = 426.7914pt
(typearea)              DIV departure   = -1%
(typearea)              \evensidemargin = 22.57254pt
(typearea)              \oddsidemargin  = 3.60402pt
(typearea)             \paperheight     = 845.04694pt
(typearea)              \textheight     = 635.5pt
(typearea)              \topmargin      = -41.72441pt
(typearea)              \headheight     = 18.125pt
(typearea)              \headsep        = 21.75pt
(typearea)              \topskip        = 12.0pt
(typearea)              \footskip       = 50.75pt
(typearea)              \baselineskip   = 14.5pt
(typearea)              on input line 1740.
)
\c@part=\count176
\c@chapter=\count177
\c@section=\count178
\c@subsection=\count179
\c@subsubsection=\count180
\c@paragraph=\count181
\c@subparagraph=\count182
\scr@dte@chapter@maxnumwidth=\skip53
Class scrreprt Info: using compatibility default `afterindent=bysign'
(scrreprt)           for `\chapter on input line 5627.
\scr@dte@section@maxnumwidth=\skip54
Class scrreprt Info: using compatibility default `runin=bysign'
(scrreprt)           for `\section on input line 5638.
Class scrreprt Info: using compatibility default `afterindent=bysign'
(scrreprt)           for `\section on input line 5638.
\scr@dte@part@maxnumwidth=\skip55
Class scrreprt Info: using compatibility default `afterindent=true'
(scrreprt)           for `\part on input line 5647.
\scr@dte@subsection@maxnumwidth=\skip56
Class scrreprt Info: using compatibility default `runin=bysign'
(scrreprt)           for `\subsection on input line 5657.
Class scrreprt Info: using compatibility default `afterindent=bysign'
(scrreprt)           for `\subsection on input line 5657.
\scr@dte@subsubsection@maxnumwidth=\skip57
Class scrreprt Info: using compatibility default `runin=bysign'
(scrreprt)           for `\subsubsection on input line 5667.
Class scrreprt Info: using compatibility default `afterindent=bysign'
(scrreprt)           for `\subsubsection on input line 5667.
\scr@dte@paragraph@maxnumwidth=\skip58
Class scrreprt Info: using compatibility default `runin=bysign'
(scrreprt)           for `\paragraph on input line 5678.
Class scrreprt Info: using compatibility default `afterindent=bysign'
(scrreprt)           for `\paragraph on input line 5678.
\scr@dte@subparagraph@maxnumwidth=\skip59
Class scrreprt Info: using compatibility default `runin=bysign'
(scrreprt)           for `\subparagraph on input line 5688.
Class scrreprt Info: using compatibility default `afterindent=bysign'
(scrreprt)           for `\subparagraph on input line 5688.
\abovecaptionskip=\skip60
\belowcaptionskip=\skip61
\c@pti@nb@sid@b@x=\box48
Package tocbasic Info: babel extension for `lof' omitted
(tocbasic)             because of missing \bbl@set@language on input line 6925.

\scr@dte@figure@maxnumwidth=\skip62
\c@figure=\count183
Package tocbasic Info: babel extension for `lot' omitted
(tocbasic)             because of missing \bbl@set@language on input line 6942.

\scr@dte@table@maxnumwidth=\skip63
\c@table=\count184
Class scrreprt Info: Redefining `\numberline' on input line 7111.
\bibindent=\dimen138
)
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/generic/babel\babel.sty"
Package: babel 2020/10/27 3.51 The Babel package

("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/generic/babel\babel.def"
File: babel.def 2020/10/27 3.51 Babel common definitions
\babel@savecnt=\count185
\U@D=\dimen139
\l@babelnohyphens=\language79

("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/generic/babel\txtbabel.def")
\bbl@readstream=\read2
)
\bbl@dirlevel=\count186

*************************************
* Local config file bblopts.cfg used
*
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/latex/arabi\bblopts.cfg"
File: bblopts.cfg 2005/09/08 v0.1 add Arabic and Farsi to "declared" options of
 babel
)
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/latex/babel-english\english.ldf"
Language: english 2017/06/06 v3.3r English support from the babel system
Package babel Info: \l@canadian = using hyphenrules for english
(babel)             (\language0) on input line 102.
Package babel Info: \l@australian = using hyphenrules for ukenglish
(babel)             (\language73) on input line 105.
Package babel Info: \l@newzealand = using hyphenrules for ukenglish
(babel)             (\language73) on input line 108.
)
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/latex/babel-german\naustrian.ldf"
Language: naustrian 2020/07/21 v2.12 German support for babel (post-1996 orthog
raphy)

("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/latex/babel-german\ngermanb.ldf"
Language: ngermanb 2020/07/21 v2.12 German support for babel (post-1996 orthogr
aphy)
Package babel Info: \l@naustrian = using hyphenrules for ngerman
(babel)             (\language48) on input line 55.
Package babel Info: Making " an active character on input line 121.
)))
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/latex/pdfx\pdfx.sty"
Package: pdfx 2019/02/27 v1.6.3 PDF/X and PDF/A support (CVR/HTH/RRM/PS)
\pdfx@minorversion=\count187

("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/generic/iftex\iftex.sty"
Package: iftex 2020/03/06 v1.0d TeX engine tests
)
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/generic/iftex\ifpdf.sty"
Package: ifpdf 2019/10/25 v3.4 ifpdf legacy package. Use iftex instead.
)
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/generic/iftex\ifxetex.sty"
Package: ifxetex 2019/10/25 v0.7 ifxetex legacy package. Use iftex instead.
)
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/latex/base\everyshi-ltx.sty"
Package: everyshi-ltx 2020/08/17 v1.0a Emulation of the original everyshi packa
ge
with kernel methods
)
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/generic/iftex\ifluatex.sty"
Package: ifluatex 2019/10/25 v1.5 ifluatex legacy package. Use iftex instead.
){C:/Users/Gerold/AppData/Local/MiKTeX/2.9/pdftex/config/pdftex.map}
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/latex/base\inputenc.sty"
Package: inputenc 2020/08/01 v1.3d Input encoding file
\inpenc@prehook=\toks16
\inpenc@posthook=\toks17
)
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/latex/pdfx\l8u-penc.def"
File: l8u-penc.def 2017/06/23 v0.8 Custom LaTeX file, for UTF8 encoded letters 
and symbols
LaTeX Info: Composite with undeclared \b in encoding L8U on input line 278.
)
\pdfxsafeforxmp@toks=\toks18

("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/latex/xcolor\xcolor.sty"
Package: xcolor 2016/05/11 v2.12 LaTeX color extensions (UK)

("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/latex/graphics-cfg\color.cfg"
File: color.cfg 2016/01/02 v1.6 sample color configuration
)
Package xcolor Info: Driver file: pdftex.def on input line 225.

("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/latex/graphics-def\pdftex.def"
File: pdftex.def 2020/10/05 v1.2a Graphics/color driver for pdftex
)
Package xcolor Info: Model `cmy' substituted by `cmy0' on input line 1348.
Package xcolor Info: Model `hsb' substituted by `rgb' on input line 1352.
Package xcolor Info: Model `RGB' extended on input line 1364.
Package xcolor Info: Model `HTML' substituted by `rgb' on input line 1366.
Package xcolor Info: Model `Hsb' substituted by `hsb' on input line 1367.
Package xcolor Info: Model `tHsb' substituted by `hsb' on input line 1368.
Package xcolor Info: Model `HSB' substituted by `hsb' on input line 1369.
Package xcolor Info: Model `Gray' substituted by `gray' on input line 1370.
Package xcolor Info: Model `wave' substituted by `hsb' on input line 1371.
)
\pdfx@tmptoks=\toks19

("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/latex/hyperref\hyperref.sty"
Package: hyperref 2020-05-15 v7.00e Hypertext links for LaTeX

("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/generic/ltxcmds\ltxcmds.sty"
Package: ltxcmds 2020-05-10 v1.25 LaTeX kernel commands for general use (HO)
)
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/generic/pdftexcmds\pdftexcmds.sty"
Package: pdftexcmds 2020-06-27 v0.33 Utility functions of pdfTeX for LuaTeX (HO
)

("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/generic/infwarerr\infwarerr.sty"
Package: infwarerr 2019/12/03 v1.5 Providing info/warning/error messages (HO)
)
Package pdftexcmds Info: \pdf@primitive is available.
Package pdftexcmds Info: \pdf@ifprimitive is available.
Package pdftexcmds Info: \pdfdraftmode found.
)
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/generic/kvsetkeys\kvsetkeys.sty"
Package: kvsetkeys 2019/12/15 v1.18 Key value parser (HO)
)
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/generic/kvdefinekeys\kvdefinekeys.sty"
Package: kvdefinekeys 2019-12-19 v1.6 Define keys (HO)
)
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/generic/pdfescape\pdfescape.sty"
Package: pdfescape 2019/12/09 v1.15 Implements pdfTeX's escape features (HO)
)
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/latex/hycolor\hycolor.sty"
Package: hycolor 2020-01-27 v1.10 Color options for hyperref/bookmark (HO)
)
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/latex/letltxmacro\letltxmacro.sty"
Package: letltxmacro 2019/12/03 v1.6 Let assignment for LaTeX macros (HO)
)
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/latex/auxhook\auxhook.sty"
Package: auxhook 2019-12-17 v1.6 Hooks for auxiliary files (HO)
)
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/latex/kvoptions\kvoptions.sty"
Package: kvoptions 2019/11/29 v3.13 Key value format for package options (HO)
)
\@linkdim=\dimen140
\Hy@linkcounter=\count188
\Hy@pagecounter=\count189

("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/latex/hyperref\pd1enc.def"
File: pd1enc.def 2020-05-15 v7.00e Hyperref: PDFDocEncoding definition (HO)
)
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/generic/intcalc\intcalc.sty"
Package: intcalc 2019/12/15 v1.3 Expandable calculations with integers (HO)
)
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/generic/etexcmds\etexcmds.sty"
Package: etexcmds 2019/12/15 v1.7 Avoid name clashes with e-TeX commands (HO)
)
\Hy@SavedSpaceFactor=\count190
Package hyperref Info: Option `hyperfootnotes' set `false' on input line 4338.
Package hyperref Info: Option `pdfa' set `true' on input line 4338.
Package hyperref Info: Hyper figures OFF on input line 4464.
Package hyperref Info: Link nesting OFF on input line 4469.
Package hyperref Info: Hyper index ON on input line 4472.
Package hyperref Info: Plain pages OFF on input line 4479.
Package hyperref Info: Backreferencing OFF on input line 4484.
Package hyperref Info: Implicit mode ON; LaTeX internals redefined.
Package hyperref Info: Bookmarks ON on input line 4717.
\c@Hy@tempcnt=\count191

("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/latex/url\url.sty"
\Urlmuskip=\muskip16
Package: url 2013/09/16  ver 3.4  Verb mode for urls, etc.
)
LaTeX Info: Redefining \url on input line 5076.
\XeTeXLinkMargin=\dimen141

("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/generic/bitset\bitset.sty"
Package: bitset 2019/12/09 v1.3 Handle bit-vector datatype (HO)

("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/generic/bigintcalc\bigintcalc.sty"
Package: bigintcalc 2019/12/15 v1.5 Expandable calculations on big integers (HO
)
))
\Fld@menulength=\count192
\Field@Width=\dimen142
\Fld@charsize=\dimen143
Package hyperref Info: Hyper figures OFF on input line 6347.
Package hyperref Info: Link nesting OFF on input line 6352.
Package hyperref Info: Hyper index ON on input line 6355.
Package hyperref Info: backreferencing OFF on input line 6362.
Package hyperref Info: Link coloring OFF on input line 6367.
Package hyperref Info: Link coloring with OCG OFF on input line 6372.
Package hyperref Info: PDF/A mode ON on input line 6375.
LaTeX Info: Redefining \ref on input line 6417.
LaTeX Info: Redefining \pageref on input line 6421.

("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/latex/base\atbegshi-ltx.sty"
Package: atbegshi-ltx 2020/08/17 v1.0a Emulation of the original atbegshi packa
ge
with kernel methods
)
\Hy@abspage=\count193
\c@Item=\count194
)
Package hyperref Info: Driver: hpdftex.

("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/latex/hyperref\hpdftex.def"
File: hpdftex.def 2020-05-15 v7.00e Hyperref driver for pdfTeX

("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/latex/base\atveryend-ltx.sty"
Package: atveryend-ltx 2020/08/19 v1.0a Emulation of the original atvery packag
e
with kernel methods
)
\Fld@listcount=\count195
\c@bookmark@seq@number=\count196

("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/latex/rerunfilecheck\rerunfilecheck.sty"
Package: rerunfilecheck 2019/12/05 v1.9 Rerun checks for auxiliary files (HO)

("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/generic/uniquecounter\uniquecounter.sty"
Package: uniquecounter 2019/12/15 v1.4 Provide unlimited unique counter (HO)
)
Package uniquecounter Info: New unique counter `rerunfilecheck' on input line 2
86.
)
\Hy@SectionHShift=\skip64
)
Package hyperref Info: Option `unicode' set `true' on input line 1463.

("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/latex/hyperref\puenc.def"
File: puenc.def 2020-05-15 v7.00e Hyperref: PDF Unicode definition (HO)
)
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/generic/stringenc\stringenc.sty"
Package: stringenc 2019/11/29 v1.12 Convert strings between diff. encodings (HO
)
)
Package hyperref Info: Option `psdextra' set `true' on input line 1465.

("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/latex/hyperref\psdextra.def"
File: psdextra.def 2020-05-15 v7.00e Hyperref: Additions to PDF string support
)
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/generic/colorprofiles\colorprofiles.sty"
Package: colorprofiles 2018/11/01 v1.0.1 color profiles for PDF/X and PDF/A sup
port

("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/generic/colorprofiles\colorprofiles.tex"))
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/generic/stringenc\se-pdfdoc.def"
File: se-pdfdoc.def 2019/11/29 v1.12 stringenc: PDFDocEncoding
)
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/latex/pdfx\AdobeColorProfiles.tex")
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/latex/pdfx\8bit.def"
File: 8bit.def 2008/03/30 v1.1d Input encoding file
)
** pdfx: Metadata file main.xmpdata read successfully.
(main.xmpdata)<<sRGB.icc>> ("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/latex/pdfx\8bit.de
f"
File: 8bit.def 2008/03/30 v1.1d Input encoding file
) ("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/latex/pdfx\8bit.def"
File: 8bit.def 2008/03/30 v1.1d Input encoding file
)
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/generic/stringenc\se-utf8.def"
File: se-utf8.def 2019/11/29 v1.12 stringenc: UTF-8
)
Package hyperref Info: Option `unicode' set `true' on input line 2411.
Package hyperref Info: Option `unicode' set `true' on input line 2412.

("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/latex/pdfx\8bit.def"
File: 8bit.def 2008/03/30 v1.1d Input encoding file
)
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/generic/pdftex\glyphtounicode.tex")
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/latex/pdfx\glyphtounicode-cmr.tex")
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/latex/pdfx\glyphtounicode-ntx.tex")
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/latex/base\ifthen.sty"
Package: ifthen 2014/09/29 v1.1c Standard LaTeX ifthen package (DPC)
)
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/latex/xmpincl\xmpincl.sty"
Package: xmpincl 2008/05/10 v2.2 Include XMP data in pdflatex
)
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/latex/pdfx\8bit.def"
File: 8bit.def 2008/03/30 v1.1d Input encoding file
)
Using XMP template file: pdfa.xmp
\xmpinclWrite=\write3
\xmpinclRead=\read3
\openout3 = `pdfa.xmpi'.

<<pdfa.xmpi>>) ("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/latex/base\fontenc.sty"
Package: fontenc 2020/08/10 v2.0s Standard LaTeX package
)
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/latex/base\inputenc.sty"
Package: inputenc 2020/08/01 v1.3d Input encoding file
)
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/latex/setspace\setspace.sty"
Package: setspace 2011/12/19 v6.7a set line spacing
)
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/latex/mathdesign\mathdesign.sty"
Package: mathdesign 2013/08/29 v2.31 Math Design Project

("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/latex/mathdesign/mdbch\mdbch.cfg")
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/latex/mathdesign/mdbch\mdbch.sty"
Package: mdbch 2013/08/29 v2.31 bitstream bitstream charter + mdbch (Math Desig
n Project)

("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/latex/mathdesign\mdfont.def"
File: mdfont.def 2013/08/29 v2.31 (Math Design Project)
)
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/latex/mathdesign\mdsffont.def"
File: mdsffont.def 2013/08/29 v2.31 (Math Design Project)


LaTeX Warning: Font shape declaration has incorrect series value `mc'.
               It should not contain an `m'! Please correct it.
               Found on input line 53.


LaTeX Warning: Font shape declaration has incorrect series value `mc'.
               It should not contain an `m'! Please correct it.
               Found on input line 56.


LaTeX Warning: Font shape declaration has incorrect series value `mc'.
               It should not contain an `m'! Please correct it.
               Found on input line 59.


LaTeX Warning: Font shape declaration has incorrect series value `mc'.
               It should not contain an `m'! Please correct it.
               Found on input line 79.


LaTeX Warning: Font shape declaration has incorrect series value `mc'.
               It should not contain an `m'! Please correct it.
               Found on input line 102.


LaTeX Warning: Font shape declaration has incorrect series value `mc'.
               It should not contain an `m'! Please correct it.
               Found on input line 105.


LaTeX Warning: Font shape declaration has incorrect series value `mc'.
               It should not contain an `m'! Please correct it.
               Found on input line 108.


LaTeX Warning: Font shape declaration has incorrect series value `mc'.
               It should not contain an `m'! Please correct it.
               Found on input line 128.


LaTeX Warning: Font shape declaration has incorrect series value `mc'.
               It should not contain an `m'! Please correct it.
               Found on input line 259.


LaTeX Warning: Font shape declaration has incorrect series value `mc'.
               It should not contain an `m'! Please correct it.
               Found on input line 262.


LaTeX Warning: Font shape declaration has incorrect series value `mc'.
               It should not contain an `m'! Please correct it.
               Found on input line 265.


LaTeX Warning: Font shape declaration has incorrect series value `mc'.
               It should not contain an `m'! Please correct it.
               Found on input line 268.


LaTeX Warning: Font shape declaration has incorrect series value `mc'.
               It should not contain an `m'! Please correct it.
               Found on input line 313.


LaTeX Warning: Font shape declaration has incorrect series value `mc'.
               It should not contain an `m'! Please correct it.
               Found on input line 316.


LaTeX Warning: Font shape declaration has incorrect series value `mc'.
               It should not contain an `m'! Please correct it.
               Found on input line 319.


LaTeX Warning: Font shape declaration has incorrect series value `mc'.
               It should not contain an `m'! Please correct it.
               Found on input line 322.

) ("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/latex/mathdesign\mdttfont.def"
File: mdttfont.def 2013/08/29 v2.31 (Math Design Project)
)
\symmdcal=\mathgroup4
LaTeX Font Info:    Overwriting symbol font `mdcal' in version `bold'
(Font)                  OMS/mdbch/m/n --> OMS/mdbch/b/n on input line 97.
\symmdscr=\mathgroup5
LaTeX Font Info:    Overwriting symbol font `mdscr' in version `bold'
(Font)                  OMS/mdbch/m/n --> OMS/mdbch/b/n on input line 103.
LaTeX Font Info:    Overwriting math alphabet `\mathfrak' in version `bold'
(Font)                  U/xmdeuf/m/n --> U/xmdeuf/b/n on input line 110.
LaTeX Font Info:    Overwriting symbol font `operators' in version `normal'
(Font)                  OT1/cmr/m/n --> OT1/mdbch/m/n on input line 121.
LaTeX Font Info:    Overwriting symbol font `letters' in version `normal'
(Font)                  OML/cmm/m/it --> OML/mdbch/m/it on input line 122.
LaTeX Font Info:    Overwriting symbol font `symbols' in version `normal'
(Font)                  OMS/cmsy/m/n --> OMS/mdbch/m/n on input line 123.
LaTeX Font Info:    Overwriting symbol font `largesymbols' in version `normal'
(Font)                  OMX/cmex/m/n --> OMX/mdbch/m/n on input line 124.
LaTeX Font Info:    Overwriting symbol font `operators' in version `bold'
(Font)                  OT1/cmr/bx/n --> OT1/mdbch/b/n on input line 126.
LaTeX Font Info:    Overwriting symbol font `letters' in version `bold'
(Font)                  OML/cmm/b/it --> OML/mdbch/b/it on input line 127.
LaTeX Font Info:    Overwriting symbol font `symbols' in version `bold'
(Font)                  OMS/cmsy/b/n --> OMS/mdbch/b/n on input line 128.
LaTeX Font Info:    Overwriting symbol font `largesymbols' in version `bold'
(Font)                  OMX/cmex/m/n --> OMX/mdbch/b/n on input line 129.
LaTeX Font Info:    Overwriting math alphabet `\mathrm' in version `normal'
(Font)                  OT1/mdbch/m/n --> T1/mdbch/m/n on input line 131.
LaTeX Font Info:    Overwriting math alphabet `\mathbf' in version `normal'
(Font)                  OT1/cmr/bx/n --> T1/mdbch/b/n on input line 132.
LaTeX Font Info:    Overwriting math alphabet `\mathit' in version `normal'
(Font)                  OT1/cmr/m/it --> T1/mdbch/m/it on input line 133.
LaTeX Font Info:    Overwriting math alphabet `\mathsf' in version `normal'
(Font)                  OT1/cmss/m/n --> T1/cmss/m/n on input line 134.
LaTeX Font Info:    Overwriting math alphabet `\mathtt' in version `normal'
(Font)                  OT1/cmtt/m/n --> T1/cmtt/m/n on input line 135.
LaTeX Font Info:    Overwriting math alphabet `\mathrm' in version `bold'
(Font)                  OT1/mdbch/b/n --> T1/mdbch/b/n on input line 137.
LaTeX Font Info:    Overwriting math alphabet `\mathbf' in version `bold'
(Font)                  OT1/cmr/bx/n --> T1/mdbch/b/n on input line 138.
LaTeX Font Info:    Overwriting math alphabet `\mathit' in version `bold'
(Font)                  OT1/cmr/bx/it --> T1/mdbch/b/it on input line 139.
LaTeX Font Info:    Overwriting math alphabet `\mathsf' in version `bold'
(Font)                  OT1/cmss/bx/n --> T1/cmss/b/n on input line 140.
LaTeX Font Info:    Overwriting math alphabet `\mathtt' in version `bold'
(Font)                  OT1/cmtt/m/n --> T1/cmtt/b/n on input line 141.
\symlettersupright=\mathgroup6
LaTeX Font Info:    Overwriting symbol font `lettersupright' in version `bold'
(Font)                  OML/mdbch/m/n --> OML/mdbch/b/n on input line 144.
LaTeX Font Info:    Redeclaring math alphabet \mathrm on input line 145.
LaTeX Font Info:    Overwriting math alphabet `\mathcal' in version `normal'
(Font)                  OMS/mdbch/m/n --> OMS/mdbch/m/n on input line 167.

("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/latex/xkeyval\xkeyval.sty"
Package: xkeyval 2020/11/20 v2.8 package option processing (HA)

! I can't find file `xkeyval'.
l.39 ...XKeyValLoaded\endinput\else\input xkeyval 
                                                  \fi
Please type another input file name
! Emergency stop.
l.39 ...XKeyValLoaded\endinput\else\input xkeyval 
                                                  \fi
*** (job aborted, file error in nonstop mode)

 
Here is how much of TeX's memory you used:
 15643 strings out of 479799
 248804 string characters out of 2877695
 666959 words of memory out of 3000000
 32434 multiletter control sequences out of 15000+200000
 536150 words of font info for 31 fonts, out of 3000000 for 9000
 1142 hyphenation exceptions out of 8191
 110i,1n,113p,10627b,2422s stack positions out of 5000i,500n,10000p,200000b,50000s
!  ==> Fatal error occurred, no output PDF file produced!
````
`````

Comment: the package installation is faulty, I will open an issue at the miktex issue tracker.

Comment: miktex is missing some xkeyval files you could get xkeyval  from ctan until that is fixed

Comment: I opened an issue https://github.com/MiKTeX/miktex-packaging/issues/207

Comment: mathdesign is loading xkeyval in your case. You could comment it until the next update.

Comment: I looked up the xkeyval package on CTAN. I can only find the .dtx file for the documentation but no .ins file or other package files.

Comment: run latex on the dtx, this will probably extract the files.

Comment: I have the same problem here. It should be solved tomorrow, according to the [issue opened on github](https://github.com/MiKTeX/miktex-packaging/issues/207).

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem after updating yesterday.

I fixed it by installing it manually with @ulrike-fischer's suggestion.

Steps to perform:

1. Download xkeyval from ctan (.dtx)
2. Put the file in a temporary folder and open a terminal
3. Run `latex xkeyval.dtx`
4. (maybe optional) I needed to repeat step 3, so executed latex two times on the .dtx file, but I don't know if it is necessary
5. Copy and replace  all the files generated to `C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\xkeyval` or whereever you have installed xkeyval with miktex
6. Enjoy compilation working again

Hope it works for you mate and thanks for @ulrike-fischer's suggestion.

Comment: I did not try out this solution as I was able to restore an older version of xkeyval, but thanks for the info.

Answer (score 0):

Mathador is correct this was a bug in MiKTeX. If you do an update of MiKTeX (I needed to do it in Admin mode for my installation) it is all fixed