# XCharter broken after MikTeX Update?

Tags: miktex, xcharter

I am writing a document using TexStudio and MikTeX as package source. Today I updated some packages including XCharter. Now this package seems to be broken (see also [I can't find file `xkeyval´](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/572275/i-cant-find-file-xkeyval%c2%b4)).

A minimal example does not compile and throws following error:

```
`! Font T1/XCharter-TOsF/m/n/10=XCharter1-Roman-tosf-t1 at 9.60007pt not loadable: Metric (TFM) file not found.
```

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\usepackage[charter,expert]{mathdesign}
\usepackage[scaled=.96,osf]{XCharter}

\begin{document}
Hello World
\end{document}
```

Could this be related to [I can't find file `xkeyval´](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/572275/i-cant-find-file-xkeyval%c2%b4) ?

The log file:

`````
entering extended mode
**./document.tex
(document.tex
LaTeX2e <2020-10-01> patch level 2
L3 programming layer <2020-10-27> xparse <2020-03-03>
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX\tex/latex/base\article.cls"
Document Class: article 2020/04/10 v1.4m Standard LaTeX document class
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX\tex/latex/base\size10.clo"
File: size10.clo 2020/04/10 v1.4m Standard LaTeX file (size option)
)
\c@part=\count175
\c@section=\count176
\c@subsection=\count177
\c@subsubsection=\count178
\c@paragraph=\count179
\c@subparagraph=\count180
\c@figure=\count181
\c@table=\count182
\abovecaptionskip=\skip47
\belowcaptionskip=\skip48
\bibindent=\dimen138
)
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX\tex/latex/base\fontenc.sty"
Package: fontenc 2020/08/10 v2.0s Standard LaTeX package
)
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX\tex/latex/base\inputenc.sty"
Package: inputenc 2020/08/01 v1.3d Input encoding file
\inpenc@prehook=\toks15
\inpenc@posthook=\toks16
)
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX\tex/latex/mathdesign\mathdesign.sty"
Package: mathdesign 2013/08/29 v2.31 Math Design Project

("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX\tex/latex/graphics\keyval.sty"
Package: keyval 2014/10/28 v1.15 key=value parser (DPC)
\KV@toks@=\toks17
)
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX\tex/latex/base\ifthen.sty"
Package: ifthen 2014/09/29 v1.1c Standard LaTeX ifthen package (DPC)
)
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX\tex/latex/mathdesign/mdbch\mdbch.cfg")
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX\tex/latex/mathdesign/mdbch\mdbch.sty"
Package: mdbch 2013/08/29 v2.31 bitstream bitstream charter + mdbch (Math Desig
n Project)

("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX\tex/latex/mathdesign\mdfont.def"
File: mdfont.def 2013/08/29 v2.31 (Math Design Project)
)
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX\tex/latex/mathdesign\mdsffont.def"
File: mdsffont.def 2013/08/29 v2.31 (Math Design Project)


LaTeX Warning: Font shape declaration has incorrect series value `mc'.
               It should not contain an `m'! Please correct it.
               Found on input line 53.


LaTeX Warning: Font shape declaration has incorrect series value `mc'.
               It should not contain an `m'! Please correct it.
               Found on input line 56.


LaTeX Warning: Font shape declaration has incorrect series value `mc'.
               It should not contain an `m'! Please correct it.
               Found on input line 59.


LaTeX Warning: Font shape declaration has incorrect series value `mc'.
               It should not contain an `m'! Please correct it.
               Found on input line 79.


LaTeX Warning: Font shape declaration has incorrect series value `mc'.
               It should not contain an `m'! Please correct it.
               Found on input line 102.


LaTeX Warning: Font shape declaration has incorrect series value `mc'.
               It should not contain an `m'! Please correct it.
               Found on input line 105.


LaTeX Warning: Font shape declaration has incorrect series value `mc'.
               It should not contain an `m'! Please correct it.
               Found on input line 108.


LaTeX Warning: Font shape declaration has incorrect series value `mc'.
               It should not contain an `m'! Please correct it.
               Found on input line 128.


LaTeX Warning: Font shape declaration has incorrect series value `mc'.
               It should not contain an `m'! Please correct it.
               Found on input line 259.


LaTeX Warning: Font shape declaration has incorrect series value `mc'.
               It should not contain an `m'! Please correct it.
               Found on input line 262.


LaTeX Warning: Font shape declaration has incorrect series value `mc'.
               It should not contain an `m'! Please correct it.
               Found on input line 265.


LaTeX Warning: Font shape declaration has incorrect series value `mc'.
               It should not contain an `m'! Please correct it.
               Found on input line 268.


LaTeX Warning: Font shape declaration has incorrect series value `mc'.
               It should not contain an `m'! Please correct it.
               Found on input line 313.


LaTeX Warning: Font shape declaration has incorrect series value `mc'.
               It should not contain an `m'! Please correct it.
               Found on input line 316.


LaTeX Warning: Font shape declaration has incorrect series value `mc'.
               It should not contain an `m'! Please correct it.
               Found on input line 319.


LaTeX Warning: Font shape declaration has incorrect series value `mc'.
               It should not contain an `m'! Please correct it.
               Found on input line 322.

) ("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX\tex/latex/mathdesign\mdttfont.def"
File: mdttfont.def 2013/08/29 v2.31 (Math Design Project)
)
\symmdcal=\mathgroup4
LaTeX Font Info:    Overwriting symbol font `mdcal' in version `bold'
(Font)                  OMS/mdbch/m/n --> OMS/mdbch/b/n on input line 97.
\symmdscr=\mathgroup5
LaTeX Font Info:    Overwriting symbol font `mdscr' in version `bold'
(Font)                  OMS/mdbch/m/n --> OMS/mdbch/b/n on input line 103.
LaTeX Font Info:    Overwriting math alphabet `\mathfrak' in version `bold'
(Font)                  U/xmdeuf/m/n --> U/xmdeuf/b/n on input line 110.
LaTeX Font Info:    Overwriting symbol font `operators' in version `normal'
(Font)                  OT1/cmr/m/n --> OT1/mdbch/m/n on input line 121.
LaTeX Font Info:    Overwriting symbol font `letters' in version `normal'
(Font)                  OML/cmm/m/it --> OML/mdbch/m/it on input line 122.
LaTeX Font Info:    Overwriting symbol font `symbols' in version `normal'
(Font)                  OMS/cmsy/m/n --> OMS/mdbch/m/n on input line 123.
LaTeX Font Info:    Overwriting symbol font `largesymbols' in version `normal'
(Font)                  OMX/cmex/m/n --> OMX/mdbch/m/n on input line 124.
LaTeX Font Info:    Overwriting symbol font `operators' in version `bold'
(Font)                  OT1/cmr/bx/n --> OT1/mdbch/b/n on input line 126.
LaTeX Font Info:    Overwriting symbol font `letters' in version `bold'
(Font)                  OML/cmm/b/it --> OML/mdbch/b/it on input line 127.
LaTeX Font Info:    Overwriting symbol font `symbols' in version `bold'
(Font)                  OMS/cmsy/b/n --> OMS/mdbch/b/n on input line 128.
LaTeX Font Info:    Overwriting symbol font `largesymbols' in version `bold'
(Font)                  OMX/cmex/m/n --> OMX/mdbch/b/n on input line 129.
LaTeX Font Info:    Overwriting math alphabet `\mathrm' in version `normal'
(Font)                  OT1/mdbch/m/n --> T1/mdbch/m/n on input line 131.
LaTeX Font Info:    Overwriting math alphabet `\mathbf' in version `normal'
(Font)                  OT1/cmr/bx/n --> T1/mdbch/b/n on input line 132.
LaTeX Font Info:    Overwriting math alphabet `\mathit' in version `normal'
(Font)                  OT1/cmr/m/it --> T1/mdbch/m/it on input line 133.
LaTeX Font Info:    Overwriting math alphabet `\mathsf' in version `normal'
(Font)                  OT1/cmss/m/n --> T1/cmss/m/n on input line 134.
LaTeX Font Info:    Overwriting math alphabet `\mathtt' in version `normal'
(Font)                  OT1/cmtt/m/n --> T1/cmtt/m/n on input line 135.
LaTeX Font Info:    Overwriting math alphabet `\mathrm' in version `bold'
(Font)                  OT1/mdbch/b/n --> T1/mdbch/b/n on input line 137.
LaTeX Font Info:    Overwriting math alphabet `\mathbf' in version `bold'
(Font)                  OT1/cmr/bx/n --> T1/mdbch/b/n on input line 138.
LaTeX Font Info:    Overwriting math alphabet `\mathit' in version `bold'
(Font)                  OT1/cmr/bx/it --> T1/mdbch/b/it on input line 139.
LaTeX Font Info:    Overwriting math alphabet `\mathsf' in version `bold'
(Font)                  OT1/cmss/bx/n --> T1/cmss/b/n on input line 140.
LaTeX Font Info:    Overwriting math alphabet `\mathtt' in version `bold'
(Font)                  OT1/cmtt/m/n --> T1/cmtt/b/n on input line 141.
\symlettersupright=\mathgroup6
LaTeX Font Info:    Overwriting symbol font `lettersupright' in version `bold'
(Font)                  OML/mdbch/m/n --> OML/mdbch/b/n on input line 144.
LaTeX Font Info:    Redeclaring math alphabet \mathrm on input line 145.
LaTeX Font Info:    Overwriting math alphabet `\mathcal' in version `normal'
(Font)                  OMS/mdbch/m/n --> OMS/mdbch/m/n on input line 167.

("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX\tex/latex/xkeyval\xkeyval.sty"
Package: xkeyval 2014/12/03 v2.7a package option processing (HA)

("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX\tex/generic/xkeyval\xkeyval.tex"
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX\tex/generic/xkeyval\xkvutils.tex"
\XKV@toks=\toks18
\XKV@tempa@toks=\toks19
)
\XKV@depth=\count183
File: xkeyval.tex 2014/12/03 v2.7a key=value parser (HA)
))
LaTeX Font Info:    Trying to load font information for T1+mdbch on input line 
186.

("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX\tex/latex/mathdesign/mdbch\t1mdbch.fd"
File: t1mdbch.fd 2013/08/29 Fontinst v1.933 font definitions for T1/mdbch.
)
LaTeX Font Info:    Font shape `T1/mdbch/m/n' will be
(Font)              scaled to size 9.60007pt on input line 186.
LaTeX Font Info:    Redeclaring math accent \widetilde on input line 449.
LaTeX Font Info:    Redeclaring math accent \widehat on input line 450.
Now handling font encoding MDA ...
... no UTF-8 mapping file for font encoding MDA
\symmathdesignA=\mathgroup7
LaTeX Font Info:    Overwriting symbol font `mathdesignA' in version `bold'
(Font)                  MDA/mdbch/m/n --> MDA/mdbch/b/n on input line 491.
Now handling font encoding MDB ...
... no UTF-8 mapping file for font encoding MDB
\symmathdesignB=\mathgroup8
LaTeX Font Info:    Overwriting symbol font `mathdesignB' in version `bold'
(Font)                  MDB/mdbch/m/n --> MDB/mdbch/b/n on input line 498.
\@emptytoks=\toks20
LaTeX Font Info:    Redeclaring math accent \widetilde on input line 532.
LaTeX Font Info:    Redeclaring math accent \widehat on input line 533.
\rulethickness=\skip49
)
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX\tex/latex/base\fontenc.sty"
Package: fontenc 2020/08/10 v2.0s Standard LaTeX package
))
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX\tex/latex/xcharter\XCharter.sty"
Package: XCharter 2020/09/20 v1.208

`XCharter' v1.208, 2020/09/20 Text macros for XCharter, an extension of Charter
 (msharpe) ("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX\tex/latex/base\fontenc.sty"
Package: fontenc 2020/08/10 v2.0s Standard LaTeX package

("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX\tex/latex/cyrillic\t2aenc.def"
File: t2aenc.def 2005/09/27 v1.0i Cyrillic encoding definition file
Now handling font encoding T2A ...
... processing UTF-8 mapping file for font encoding T2A

("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX\tex/latex/base\t2aenc.dfu"
File: t2aenc.dfu 2019/11/14 v1.2k UTF-8 support for inputenc
   defining Unicode char U+00A4 (decimal 164)
   defining Unicode char U+00A7 (decimal 167)
   defining Unicode char U+00AB (decimal 171)
   defining Unicode char U+00BB (decimal 187)
   defining Unicode char U+0131 (decimal 305)
   defining Unicode char U+0237 (decimal 567)
   defining Unicode char U+0400 (decimal 1024)
   defining Unicode char U+0401 (decimal 1025)
   defining Unicode char U+0402 (decimal 1026)
   defining Unicode char U+0403 (decimal 1027)
   defining Unicode char U+0404 (decimal 1028)
   defining Unicode char U+0405 (decimal 1029)
   defining Unicode char U+0406 (decimal 1030)
   defining Unicode char U+0407 (decimal 1031)
   defining Unicode char U+0408 (decimal 1032)
   defining Unicode char U+0409 (decimal 1033)
   defining Unicode char U+040A (decimal 1034)
   defining Unicode char U+040B (decimal 1035)
   defining Unicode char U+040C (decimal 1036)
   defining Unicode char U+040D (decimal 1037)
   defining Unicode char U+040E (decimal 1038)
   defining Unicode char U+040F (decimal 1039)
   defining Unicode char U+0410 (decimal 1040)
   defining Unicode char U+0411 (decimal 1041)
   defining Unicode char U+0412 (decimal 1042)
   defining Unicode char U+0413 (decimal 1043)
   defining Unicode char U+0414 (decimal 1044)
   defining Unicode char U+0415 (decimal 1045)
   defining Unicode char U+0416 (decimal 1046)
   defining Unicode char U+0417 (decimal 1047)
   defining Unicode char U+0418 (decimal 1048)
   defining Unicode char U+0419 (decimal 1049)
   defining Unicode char U+041A (decimal 1050)
   defining Unicode char U+041B (decimal 1051)
   defining Unicode char U+041C (decimal 1052)
   defining Unicode char U+041D (decimal 1053)
   defining Unicode char U+041E (decimal 1054)
   defining Unicode char U+041F (decimal 1055)
   defining Unicode char U+0420 (decimal 1056)
   defining Unicode char U+0421 (decimal 1057)
   defining Unicode char U+0422 (decimal 1058)
   defining Unicode char U+0423 (decimal 1059)
   defining Unicode char U+0424 (decimal 1060)
   defining Unicode char U+0425 (decimal 1061)
   defining Unicode char U+0426 (decimal 1062)
   defining Unicode char U+0427 (decimal 1063)
   defining Unicode char U+0428 (decimal 1064)
   defining Unicode char U+0429 (decimal 1065)
   defining Unicode char U+042A (decimal 1066)
   defining Unicode char U+042B (decimal 1067)
   defining Unicode char U+042C (decimal 1068)
   defining Unicode char U+042D (decimal 1069)
   defining Unicode char U+042E (decimal 1070)
   defining Unicode char U+042F (decimal 1071)
   defining Unicode char U+0430 (decimal 1072)
   defining Unicode char U+0431 (decimal 1073)
   defining Unicode char U+0432 (decimal 1074)
   defining Unicode char U+0433 (decimal 1075)
   defining Unicode char U+0434 (decimal 1076)
   defining Unicode char U+0435 (decimal 1077)
   defining Unicode char U+0436 (decimal 1078)
   defining Unicode char U+0437 (decimal 1079)
   defining Unicode char U+0438 (decimal 1080)
   defining Unicode char U+0439 (decimal 1081)
   defining Unicode char U+043A (decimal 1082)
   defining Unicode char U+043B (decimal 1083)
   defining Unicode char U+043C (decimal 1084)
   defining Unicode char U+043D (decimal 1085)
   defining Unicode char U+043E (decimal 1086)
   defining Unicode char U+043F (decimal 1087)
   defining Unicode char U+0440 (decimal 1088)
   defining Unicode char U+0441 (decimal 1089)
   defining Unicode char U+0442 (decimal 1090)
   defining Unicode char U+0443 (decimal 1091)
   defining Unicode char U+0444 (decimal 1092)
   defining Unicode char U+0445 (decimal 1093)
   defining Unicode char U+0446 (decimal 1094)
   defining Unicode char U+0447 (decimal 1095)
   defining Unicode char U+0448 (decimal 1096)
   defining Unicode char U+0449 (decimal 1097)
   defining Unicode char U+044A (decimal 1098)
   defining Unicode char U+044B (decimal 1099)
   defining Unicode char U+044C (decimal 1100)
   defining Unicode char U+044D (decimal 1101)
   defining Unicode char U+044E (decimal 1102)
   defining Unicode char U+044F (decimal 1103)
   defining Unicode char U+0450 (decimal 1104)
   defining Unicode char U+0451 (decimal 1105)
   defining Unicode char U+0452 (decimal 1106)
   defining Unicode char U+0453 (decimal 1107)
   defining Unicode char U+0454 (decimal 1108)
   defining Unicode char U+0455 (decimal 1109)
   defining Unicode char U+0456 (decimal 1110)
   defining Unicode char U+0457 (decimal 1111)
   defining Unicode char U+0458 (decimal 1112)
   defining Unicode char U+0459 (decimal 1113)
   defining Unicode char U+045A (decimal 1114)
   defining Unicode char U+045B (decimal 1115)
   defining Unicode char U+045C (decimal 1116)
   defining Unicode char U+045D (decimal 1117)
   defining Unicode char U+045E (decimal 1118)
   defining Unicode char U+045F (decimal 1119)
   defining Unicode char U+0490 (decimal 1168)
   defining Unicode char U+0491 (decimal 1169)
   defining Unicode char U+0492 (decimal 1170)
   defining Unicode char U+0493 (decimal 1171)
   defining Unicode char U+0496 (decimal 1174)
   defining Unicode char U+0497 (decimal 1175)
   defining Unicode char U+0498 (decimal 1176)
   defining Unicode char U+0499 (decimal 1177)
   defining Unicode char U+049A (decimal 1178)
   defining Unicode char U+049B (decimal 1179)
   defining Unicode char U+049C (decimal 1180)
   defining Unicode char U+049D (decimal 1181)
   defining Unicode char U+04A0 (decimal 1184)
   defining Unicode char U+04A1 (decimal 1185)
   defining Unicode char U+04A2 (decimal 1186)
   defining Unicode char U+04A3 (decimal 1187)
   defining Unicode char U+04A4 (decimal 1188)
   defining Unicode char U+04A5 (decimal 1189)
   defining Unicode char U+04AA (decimal 1194)
   defining Unicode char U+04AB (decimal 1195)
   defining Unicode char U+04AE (decimal 1198)
   defining Unicode char U+04AF (decimal 1199)
   defining Unicode char U+04B0 (decimal 1200)
   defining Unicode char U+04B1 (decimal 1201)
   defining Unicode char U+04B2 (decimal 1202)
   defining Unicode char U+04B3 (decimal 1203)
   defining Unicode char U+04B6 (decimal 1206)
   defining Unicode char U+04B7 (decimal 1207)
   defining Unicode char U+04B8 (decimal 1208)
   defining Unicode char U+04B9 (decimal 1209)
   defining Unicode char U+04BA (decimal 1210)
   defining Unicode char U+04BB (decimal 1211)
   defining Unicode char U+04C0 (decimal 1216)
   defining Unicode char U+04C1 (decimal 1217)
   defining Unicode char U+04C2 (decimal 1218)
   defining Unicode char U+04D0 (decimal 1232)
   defining Unicode char U+04D1 (decimal 1233)
   defining Unicode char U+04D2 (decimal 1234)
   defining Unicode char U+04D3 (decimal 1235)
   defining Unicode char U+04D4 (decimal 1236)
   defining Unicode char U+04D5 (decimal 1237)
   defining Unicode char U+04D6 (decimal 1238)
   defining Unicode char U+04D7 (decimal 1239)
   defining Unicode char U+04D8 (decimal 1240)
   defining Unicode char U+04D9 (decimal 1241)
   defining Unicode char U+04DA (decimal 1242)
   defining Unicode char U+04DB (decimal 1243)
   defining Unicode char U+04DC (decimal 1244)
   defining Unicode char U+04DD (decimal 1245)
   defining Unicode char U+04DE (decimal 1246)
   defining Unicode char U+04DF (decimal 1247)
   defining Unicode char U+04E2 (decimal 1250)
   defining Unicode char U+04E3 (decimal 1251)
   defining Unicode char U+04E4 (decimal 1252)
   defining Unicode char U+04E5 (decimal 1253)
   defining Unicode char U+04E6 (decimal 1254)
   defining Unicode char U+04E7 (decimal 1255)
   defining Unicode char U+04E8 (decimal 1256)
   defining Unicode char U+04E9 (decimal 1257)
   defining Unicode char U+04EC (decimal 1260)
   defining Unicode char U+04ED (decimal 1261)
   defining Unicode char U+04EE (decimal 1262)
   defining Unicode char U+04EF (decimal 1263)
   defining Unicode char U+04F0 (decimal 1264)
   defining Unicode char U+04F1 (decimal 1265)
   defining Unicode char U+04F2 (decimal 1266)
   defining Unicode char U+04F3 (decimal 1267)
   defining Unicode char U+04F4 (decimal 1268)
   defining Unicode char U+04F5 (decimal 1269)
   defining Unicode char U+04F8 (decimal 1272)
   defining Unicode char U+04F9 (decimal 1273)
   defining Unicode char U+200C (decimal 8204)
   defining Unicode char U+2013 (decimal 8211)
   defining Unicode char U+2014 (decimal 8212)
   defining Unicode char U+2018 (decimal 8216)
   defining Unicode char U+2019 (decimal 8217)
   defining Unicode char U+201C (decimal 8220)
   defining Unicode char U+201D (decimal 8221)
   defining Unicode char U+201E (decimal 8222)
   defining Unicode char U+2030 (decimal 8240)
   defining Unicode char U+2031 (decimal 8241)
   defining Unicode char U+2116 (decimal 8470)
   defining Unicode char U+2329 (decimal 9001)
   defining Unicode char U+232A (decimal 9002)
   defining Unicode char U+2423 (decimal 9251)
   defining Unicode char U+27E8 (decimal 10216)
   defining Unicode char U+27E9 (decimal 10217)
   defining Unicode char U+FB00 (decimal 64256)
   defining Unicode char U+FB01 (decimal 64257)
   defining Unicode char U+FB02 (decimal 64258)
   defining Unicode char U+FB03 (decimal 64259)
   defining Unicode char U+FB04 (decimal 64260)
   defining Unicode char U+FB05 (decimal 64261)
   defining Unicode char U+FB06 (decimal 64262)
))
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX\tex/latex/ly1\ly1enc.def"
File: ly1enc.def 2009/07/22 v0.7 TeX 'n ANSI encoding (DPC/KB)
Now handling font encoding LY1 ...
... processing UTF-8 mapping file for font encoding LY1

("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX\tex/latex/base\ly1enc.dfu"
File: ly1enc.dfu 2019/11/14 v1.2k UTF-8 support for inputenc
   defining Unicode char U+00A0 (decimal 160)
   
   defining Unicode char U+2039 (decimal 8249)
   defining Unicode char U+203A (decimal 8250)
   defining Unicode char U+2122 (decimal 8482)
   defining Unicode char U+FB00 (decimal 64256)
   defining Unicode char U+FB01 (decimal 64257)
   defining Unicode char U+FB02 (decimal 64258)
   defining Unicode char U+FB03 (decimal 64259)
   defining Unicode char U+FB04 (decimal 64260)
   defining Unicode char U+FB05 (decimal 64261)
   defining Unicode char U+FB06 (decimal 64262)
)))
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX\tex/latex/base\textcomp.sty"
Package: textcomp 2020/02/02 v2.0n Standard LaTeX package
)
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX\tex/latex/carlisle\scalefnt.sty")
LaTeX Font Info:    Setting XCharter-LF sub-encoding to TS1/0 on input line 16.

LaTeX Font Info:    Changing XCharter-TLF sub-encoding to TS1/0 on input line 1
6.
LaTeX Font Info:    Setting XCharter-OsF sub-encoding to TS1/0 on input line 16
.
LaTeX Font Info:    Changing XCharter-TOsF sub-encoding to TS1/0 on input line 
16.

("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX\tex/latex/etoolbox\etoolbox.sty"
Package: etoolbox 2020/10/05 v2.5k e-TeX tools for LaTeX (JAW)
\etb@tempcnta=\count184
)
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX\tex/latex/xstring\xstring.sty"
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX\tex/generic/xstring\xstring.tex"
\integerpart=\count185
\decimalpart=\count186
)
Package: xstring 2019/02/06 v1.83 String manipulations (CT)
)
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX\tex/latex/fontaxes\fontaxes.sty"
Package: fontaxes 2020/07/21 v1.0e Font selection axes
LaTeX Info: Redefining \upshape on input line 29.
LaTeX Info: Redefining \itshape on input line 31.
LaTeX Info: Redefining \slshape on input line 33.
LaTeX Info: Redefining \swshape on input line 35.
LaTeX Info: Redefining \scshape on input line 37.
LaTeX Info: Redefining \sscshape on input line 39.
LaTeX Info: Redefining \ulcshape on input line 41.
LaTeX Info: Redefining \textsw on input line 47.
LaTeX Info: Redefining \textssc on input line 48.
LaTeX Info: Redefining \textulc on input line 49.
))
LaTeX Font Info:    Trying to load font information for T1+XCharter-TOsF on inp
ut line 10.

("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX\tex/latex/xcharter\t1xcharter-tosf.fd"
File: T1XCharter-TOsF.fd 2017/06/25 (autoinst) Font definitions for T1/XCharter
-TOsF.
)
LaTeX Font Info:    Font shape `T1/XCharter-TOsF/m/n' will be
(Font)              scaled to size 9.60007pt on input line 10.

! Font T1/XCharter-TOsF/m/n/10=XCharter1-Roman-tosf-t1 at 9.60007pt not loadabl
e: Metric (TFM) file not found.
<to be read again> 
                   relax 
l.10 \begin{document}
                     
I wasn't able to read the size data for this font,
so I will ignore the font specification.
[Wizards can fix TFM files using TFtoPL/PLtoTF.]
You might try inserting a different font spec;
e.g., type `I\font<same font id>=<substitute font name>'.

("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX\tex/latex/l3backend\l3backend-pdftex.def"
File: l3backend-pdftex.def 2020-09-24 L3 backend support: PDF output (pdfTeX)
\l__kernel_color_stack_int=\count187
\l__pdf_internal_box=\box47
)
(document.aux)
\openout1 = `document.aux'.

LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for OML/cmm/m/it on input line 10.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 10.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for OMS/cmsy/m/n on input line 10.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 10.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for OT1/cmr/m/n on input line 10.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 10.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for T1/cmr/m/n on input line 10.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 10.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for TS1/cmr/m/n on input line 10.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 10.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for OMX/cmex/m/n on input line 10.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 10.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for U/cmr/m/n on input line 10.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 10.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for MDA/cmr/m/n on input line 10.
LaTeX Font Info:    Trying to load font information for MDA+cmr on input line 1
0.
 ("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX\tex/latex/mathdesign\mdacmr.fd"
File: mdacmr.fd 
)
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 10.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for MDB/cmr/m/n on input line 10.
LaTeX Font Info:    Trying to load font information for MDB+cmr on input line 1
0.

("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX\tex/latex/mathdesign\mdbcmr.fd"
File: mdbcmr.fd 
)
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 10.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for T2A/cmr/m/n on input line 10.
LaTeX Font Info:    Trying to load font information for T2A+cmr on input line 1
0.

("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX\tex/latex/cyrillic\t2acmr.fd"
File: t2acmr.fd 2001/08/11 v1.0a Computer Modern Cyrillic font definitions
)
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 10.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for LY1/ptm/m/n on input line 10.
LaTeX Font Info:    Trying to load font information for LY1+ptm on input line 1
0.

("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX\tex/latex/ly1\ly1ptm.fd"
File: ly1ptm.fd 2001/02/01 font definitions for LY1/ptm using Berry names.
)
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 10.
\c@mv@tabular=\count188
\c@mv@boldtabular=\count189
Missing character: There is no H in font nullfont!
Missing character: There is no e in font nullfont!
Missing character: There is no l in font nullfont!
Missing character: There is no l in font nullfont!
Missing character: There is no o in font nullfont!
Missing character: There is no W in font nullfont!
Missing character: There is no o in font nullfont!
Missing character: There is no r in font nullfont!
Missing character: There is no l in font nullfont!
Missing character: There is no d in font nullfont!
Missing character: There is no 1 in font nullfont!
 [1

] (document.aux) ) 
Here is how much of TeX's memory you used:
 3848 strings out of 479799
 53432 string characters out of 2879595
 299851 words of memory out of 3000000
 20815 multiletter control sequences out of 15000+200000
 537917 words of font info for 31 fonts, out of 3000000 for 9000
 1141 hyphenation exceptions out of 8191
 66i,4n,72p,262b,106s stack positions out of 5000i,500n,10000p,200000b,50000s

Output written on document.pdf (1 page, 867 bytes).
PDF statistics:
 6 PDF objects out of 1000 (max. 8388607)
 0 named destinations out of 1000 (max. 500000)
 1 words of extra memory for PDF output out of 10000 (max. 10000000)


````


  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/XKNsR.png
`````

Comment: do you have the expert fonts you are requesting in the options?

Comment: Reinstalling MikTeX without applying updates gives you version 2.7a / Mo. Dez 22 2014

Comment: Even without the expert option it does not work (which did work in the past). The error does not show but it still does not compile.

Comment: hm, I think xcharter is broken. The tfm files are missing. I will write the author.

Comment: the author will update xcharter in short time.

Comment: I tried to use the latest update from CTAN (1.213) by manually copying the files into the tex folder of the MiKTeX installation. Now the minmal example fails without showing any error. Using the document I am currently writing on shows miktex-makemf and miktex-makepk not succeeding. The log files shows The XCharter1-Roman-ts source file could not be found. and PK font XCharter1-Roman-ts1 could not be created. Is the newest update still broken or did I miss something in the manual installation? (I did refresh the font map files)

Comment: your example works fine now in texlive which already got the new version. But I can't start to test all font variants you perhaps use in your document.

Comment: Thanks for the fast reply. I deleted all XCharter related files in MiKTeX. Manually installed the tex-folder and the respective tfm and vf-files, did a refresh in MiKTeX (Administrator and User). The minimal example still fails, but now it at least shows that miktex-makemf and miktex-makepk did not succeed (PK font XCharter1-Roman-ts1 could not be created., The XCharter1-Roman-ts source file could not be found.)

Comment: I did solve the problem by manually installing the font from CTAN. It did not work before because I had overlooked some files (map-file, type1 etc). See also: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/88423/manual-font-installation